# Gzip not working on Nginx installation for domain only, but works on index.html

Tags: nginx, gzip

I am attempting to enable gzip compression on my Nginx configuration.  I have successfully added the following to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
```

I'm using https://gtmetrix.com/ to check to make sure gzip compression is on.  I also get the same results with https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

If I check my domain "https://www.hometownapparel.com", gzip is NOT being displayed as enabled.

However, if I check the web address with the index.html defined, "https://www.hometownapparel.com/index.html" gzip is indeed being listed as enabled.

What configuration mistake have I made to cause gzip not to work on just my domain name?

Regards,

Wyatt

Comment: you could try getting rid of `gzip_min_length`

Comment: Tried this.  Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following code in my sites-enabled file:

```
location / {
        index   index.php index.html;
    }
```

I switched the order of index.html, index.php, and gzip compression started working just fine...

```
location / {
        index   index.html index.php;
    }
```

Thank you.